# How can I send an email using python in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send an e-mail from a Python script that is being run on “Google App Engine”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595438/how-to-send-an-e-mail-from-a-python-script-that-is-being-run-on-google-app-engin)

I'd like to be able to trigger an email when certain things occur in my python google-app-engine app. Is there a simple way to do this? Basically, the idea is that when certain server messages are received, I'd like to get an email notification with the relevant data sent to a specific email address.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="<emailid>",subject="Output",to="<emailid>"))
message.body = ""
message.send()
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I need. Although even when using the examples on google's doc page, I still can't get the email to send, so am missing something, possibly a setup or toggle to get it working?

Comment: are u sending from the development server?

Comment: Can you please define the import statement for mail?